# How to run Devexpress report designer at runtime ?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a devexpress report,  I want to run report designer at run time , is it possible ? If possible please tell me the way

Comment: Are you trying to open dvexpress winform designer ?

Comment: Yes , I am trying to open devexpress winform designer

Comment: Ok I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very easy to do , I have wrote the  code below , that will help to do what you want

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;
// ... 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();
    ReportDesignTool dt = new ReportDesignTool(report);

    // Invoke the standard End-User Designer form. 
    dt.ShowDesigner();

    // Invoke the standard End-User Designer form modally. 
    dt.ShowDesignerDialog();

    // Invoke the Ribbon End-User Designer form. 
    dt.ShowRibbonDesigner();

    // Invoke the Ribbon End-User Designer form modally. 
    dt.ShowRibbonDesignerDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that in recent versions (e.g. 14.1), you need to add a reference to **DevExpress.XtraReports.vxx.x.Extensions.dll**

```
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UserDesigner;    
// ...

private void btnDesign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rpt = new Reports.XtraReport1();
    var designer = new ReportDesignTool(rpt);
    designer.ShowRibbonDesignerDialog();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    XtraReport1 objreport= new XtraReport1();
    ReportDesignTool objReportdesigner = new ReportDesignTool(objreport);

    // Invoke the standard End-User Designer form. 
    objReportdesigner.ShowDesigner();

    // Invoke the standard End-User Designer form modally. 
    objReportdesigner.ShowDesignerDialog();

    // Invoke the Ribbon End-User Designer form. 
    objReportdesigner.ShowRibbonDesigner();

    // Invoke the Ribbon End-User Designer form modally. 
    objReportdesigner.ShowRibbonDesignerDialog();
}
```